# IBM Watson Text-to-Speech issue with German umlaute (ä-ö-ü)

Tags: ibm-cloud, text-to-speech

I have a porblem when I want to export a .wav file.
With the English language i don't have any issues also when i want to export a German sentence without any Umlaute it works fine. But when i want to export something like "Häuschen" I can't open the file and it's also only 1KB big. Do you guys know what could be the problem?

I used the following code on WIN10

```
curl -X POST -u "apikey:{key}" ^
--header "Content-Type: application/json" ^
--header "Accept: audio/wav" ^
--data "{\"text\":\"Häuschen\"}" ^
--output Haeuschen.wav ^
"{url}/v1/voices/de-DE_ErikaV3Voice/synthesize"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce this on MacOs ... I had to replace the ^ with \ to have the correct multi line syntax, but other than that no change to your command.

```
curl -X POST -u "apikey:{key}" \ 
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \ 
--header "Accept: audio/wav" \ 
--data "{\"text\":\"Häuschen\"}" \ 
--output Haeuschen.wav \ 
"{url}/v1/voices/de-DE_ErikaV3Voice/synthesize"
```

The service returned a playable file that was 45KB big. So even this is not a solution for your problem, this gives you a data point that it should work and you can search for the right way to send this from a Windows machine now.